# Why do I get negative non-airtime in the nycflights13 dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working my way through [R4DS](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#add-new-variables-with-mutate), and am currently working with 5.5.2 Exercise. I am tasked with comparing `air_time` to `arr_time - air_time` and began by running the following code:

```
# Setting up the packages
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
install.packages("nycflights13")
library(nycflights13)

# View a tibble of the dataset
flights

# Creating a new object (lufttid = airtime) and viewing it
lufttid <- select(flights,
                  dep_time, arr_time, air_time, carrier, flight, time_hour)
lufttid
```

It would seem that `air_time` is in minutes, whilst `dep_time` and `arr_time` are formatted [t]tmm. I tested this, creating `lufttid.bedre` (`airtime.better`):

```
# lufttid.bedre <- mutate(lufttid,
                          dep_time.min = dep_time %/% 100 * 60 + dep_time %% 100,
                          arr_time.min = arr_time %/% 100 * 60 + arr_time %% 100,
                          flight_time.min = arr_time.min - dep_time.min,
                          non_air_time = flight_time.min - air_time)
lufttid.bedre
```

The numerous negative values I got in `non_air_time`, suggested that also `air_time` was in the [t]tmm format, so I improved the data frame:

```
lufttid.bedre <- mutate(lufttid,
                        dep_time.min = dep_time %/% 100 * 60 + dep_time %% 100,
                        arr_time.min = arr_time %/% 100 * 60 + arr_time %% 100,
                        air_time.min = air_time %/% 100 * 60 + air_time %% 100,
                        flight_time.min = arr_time.min - dep_time.min,
                        non_air_time = flight_time.min - air_time.min)
lufttid.bedre
```

To my surprise, I still got negative values! Either I have done something bonkers, or there are some odd values in the dataset. Can anyone with a bit more insight explain where I’ve gone wrong? If I’ve done things right, it would suggest that there are some strange values in the dataset.

Note: I couldn’t think of any good tags to add to this, so if any editors have suggestions to improve my question, it would be very much welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a little investigation in your result table (the first one seems correct to me, the air time should be displayed in minutes):

```
library(ggplot2)
lufttid.bedre %>% filter(non_air_time<=0) %>% filter(non_air_time>-500) %>%  
  ggplot(.) + geom_histogram(aes(x=non_air_time), bins=300) + geom_vline(xintercept=-60*(1:6), col="red")
```

[image]

it appears that the modes of the distribution are around -50min, -90min and -160min, and there is another mode at -1400. It strongly suggests that theses are flights with little delay to another timezones at +01h00, +02h00, +03h00 and followings (and quite a peak around 24h00 also). 
 The help file `?flights` explains that the data is all flights that daparted from NYC:

> Description :   On-time data for all flights that departed NYC (i.e. JFK,
>   LGA or EWR) in 2013.

And about the meaning of arrival times mention the local timezone.

> dep_time,arr_time :   Actual departure and arrival times, local tz.

That's enough proof to me to explain what you see. Now what you can do is start thinking of the timezone of every data, or just filter the flights that stay in the same time zone...

Comment: You answered my question well, courteously and with background information to explain your answer. Thank you so much! My apologies for a late reply, by the way.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper well it's an old answer.. I filter to only look at the negative times that the user spotted (but not too negative limit -500) to see what's happening for this variable, and then send the result to a ggplot with the piping. Is it the syntax that you don't understand?